# IEEE 1394 Firewire Card is not visible in Device Manager in WIndows 7

Tags: windows-7, firewire

I have a IEEE 1394 card that I have placed in one of the PCI slots of my Windows 7 PC. I have moved to Windows just last week and Windows is not detecting this card. It is not listed in the Device Manager. Earlier when I used Fedora 12, I was able to use this interface for capturing videos from my DV Camera.
The manufacturer is Tech-Com, which has not provided a driver CD for this.
What can I possibly try?

Answer (score 2):

From the thread [Windows 7 and Firewire problem](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprohardware/thread/65cb7a25-2a84-4875-aa27-b084537e8da1)

> Try changing your firewire driver.
>   There are 3 drivers bundled in windows 7.
>
> You can try the following steps to fix
>   our issue, This solved my initial
>   problems with a Maxtor III OneTouch
>   drive.
>
> 1. Click the Start Button, type devmgmt.msc in the “Start Search” box
>      and press Enter.
> 2. Expand the "IEEE 1394 Bus Host Controllers" node in the device tree
>      on the right hand pane
> 3. Right click the host controller node select "Update driver software
>      ..."
> 4. Select "Browse my computer for driver software"
> 5. Select "let me pick from a list of device driver on my computer ..." and
>      Check the box before “Show compatible
>      hardware”.
> 6. Choose the second option---1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller
>      (Legacy), and click next to update the
>      driver.